# How to find which computer send the print job?

Tags: c#, printing, network-programming, postscript, system.printing

I'm creating a postscript printer for windows 7 which will accept print jobs and forward them to real printers. It will be shared in the LAN and can receive print jobs from LAN computers. I want to find out from which computer a print job came from before forwarding them to a printer. How can I do this? Is the details available in the print job itself?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [GetJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144894(v=VS.85).aspx) and [EnumJobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162625(v=VS.85).aspx) spooler api functions. They both return one of two structures, [JOB_INFO_1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145019(v=VS.85).aspx) or [JOB_INFO_2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145020(v=VS.85).aspx). Each structure contains a `pMachineName` field, which is the name of the machine that created the print job. You may find the following links from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/) useful.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.JOB_INFO_1

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winspool/EnumJobs.html

Alternatively, you may also want to look into using [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=VS.85).aspx) and the [Win32_PrintJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394370(v=VS.85).aspx) class. Specifically the `HostPrintQueue` property.

Comment: Thank you very much I will check those and reply asap.